# How to set 'short' output mode in bunyan by default

Tags: node.js, logging

Regular (raw) logs in bunyan looks as following:

```
$ node myapp.js
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"myhost","pid":34572,"level":30,"msg":"start","time":"2013-01-04T07:47:25.814Z","v":0}
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"myhost","pid":34572,"widget_type":"wuzzle","level":30,"msg":"creating a wuzzle","time":"2013-01-04T07:47:25.815Z","v":0}
```

It is possible to use the "short" output mode, using the CLI, by piping logs to `bunyan -o short`

```
$ node myapp.js  | bunyan -o short
07:46:42.707Z  INFO myapp: start
07:46:42.709Z  INFO myapp: creating a wuzzle (widget_type=wuzzle)
```

Is it possible to use 'short' mode by default, so `node myapp.js` will produce short version of the logs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a custom raw stream to bunyan and write your own pretty-printer:

```
  var Logger = require('bunyan')
    , Stream = require('stream')

  var stream = new Stream()
  stream.writable = true

  stream.write = function(obj) {
     // pretty-printing your message
     console.log(obj.msg)
  }

  var logger = new Logger({
     name: 'foo',
     streams: [{
        type: "raw",
        stream: stream,
     }],
     serializers: {
        err: Logger.stdSerializers.err,
        req: Logger.stdSerializers.req,
        res: Logger.stdSerializers.res,
     },
  })

  // -------------------------------

  logger.info('hello world')
```

You can look at [this file](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/blob/master/lib/logger.js) that does exactly this job to [pretty-print](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/999113/1795553/680177b2-6a1d-11e3-82e1-02193aa4e32e.png) all messages.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk` when I try your solution (Using  NodeJS LTS v8.11.4) and TypeScript

Comment: @alex how can I use this same stream for rotating-file type?

Answer (score 0):

The bunyan cli tool actually parses the JSON that is output from running `node myapp.js`.  To have it print pretty with the short option, you will still have to pipe it to bunyan.  You can alias `bunyan -o short` by adding something to your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile depending on your system:

`alias bunyans="bunyan -o short"`

Then you could run it by doing the following:

`$ node myapp.js | bunyans`

Without piping it to bunyan (or some other tool that can parse/filter, reformat and display JSON), it will output JSON.